# GoogleDrive API Date/Time

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I am having an issue with createdDate/modifiedDate for the Google Drive API. When I get the data the time is displayed : 2012-10-26T09:27:09.382Z

Is there anyone who can guide me on how to arrange such date in a "normal" 2012-10-26 09:27:.382Z

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are RFC 3339 timestamps. This is a Python example:

```
def rfc3339_internet(date):
  d = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
  return d[:-2] + ':' + d[-2:]
```

Comment: Though not so useful because it's Phyton it's easy to translate to PHP ^^ Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the *correct* way to deal with this, but it would seem that this string could be exploded on the "T" character, and then create a new Date from the two strings produced in the new aray.

explode the date on the T

```
$date = explode('T', 2012-10-26T09:27:09.382Z);
```

$date contains an array of two pieces, what came before and after the T.

```
date('D M d, Y', strtotime($date[0]));
```

The 2nd piece will be the seconds string.

```
date('g:i:s a', strtotime($date[1]))
```

I'm not sure what the Z is in that string, but you could just str_replace the Z at this point if you don't want it to return.

```
date('g:i:s a', strtotime(str_replace('Z', '', $date[1])));
```

Comment: Thats is what I did ... Thing is if Google decides to remove the T or Z and I wouldn't know about it the date/time will be incorrect again ... I think Google must have thought about it and actually wrote something to change the date/time in the correct manner !

But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I am sure Google won't change this because this date format is the web standard RFC3339

Answer (score 0):

In Java;

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File lGoogleFile = lMyDriveHelper.getRootFile();
com.google.api.client.util.DateTime lGoogleCreatedDate = lGoogleFile.getCreatedDate();
java.util.Date lTheNormalJavaDate = new Date(lGoogleCreatedDate.getValue());
```

The Java Date behaves 'normal' ;)